# Creating a router "spreader"

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

So at my room at home, I have 2 extra computers, with like 1gb ram on each. I have the router on the other side of the wall, where a ethernat cable cannot reach it. It has to go through a wall first. (not an option at this time). So i was looking to run a server here instead of outside together with the router due to noise. My question:

Can I somehow mount an DLINK DWL-G122 wlan adapter on that computer, sending the internet through one of the computer's ethernet connectors? As another "router"?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What noise? Interference? Are you planning to attach the router to the system case? Why not just buying a wireless adapter?

Comment: This is an extremely ordinary thing to do. You didn't state which operating system (**and version!**) you're running on *any* of your computers, though, so it is impossible to help you with specific instructions. But of course you can turn any wifi adapter into an access point and route it to another device. There are so many names for the same thing because so many millions of people do this every day. IP Masquerading, layer 3 routing, (Microsoft Windows) Internet Connection Sharing, NAT, etc. etc. etc. are all synonyms for this sort of thing.

Comment: Okay, currently i'm running windows server 2008 on one of them, and the other one doesn't have a HDD. Running of a USB drive. The noise is created from its fan, annoying when watching tv, etc